# lodash vs. linq - is linq needed?

Tags: lodash

I'm coming from a C# background and am wondering how to do simple LINQ-like operations in TypeScript. I want these operations to work on LAZY iterables, NOT arrays. For example, I might want to iterate on a bunch of items and find the max, min, average after skipping the first 3, distinct only, group by and etc. I also want to generate sequences easily, like 1..1000. When looking through the lodash docs it seems to handle arrays but does not appear to handle iterables. Do I need to download something like the 'linq' library instead of lodash? Why doesn't lodash have these basic functional constructs to handle sequences? Or am I mistaken and lodash has great support for iterables?

```
function* numbers() {
    yield 4;
    yield 6;
    yield 45;
    yield 98;
    yield 10;
}

let max = _.max(numbers()); // does not compile
```

Comment: check further on lodash docs Seq and Function are quite usefull and probably can serve your requirements . I mean distinct , group by, sorting etc can all handled

Comment: What you are giving lodash in your example is not a built-in iterable. It is a generator object. [Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Comment: i read about iterators and generators. ok so now I've got a `var iterarable={}; iterables[symbol...` but can't see how to feed it into lodash. the max function, for example, takes an ArrayLike<T>, which my iterables is NOT. should be simple - want to get it in there and then be able to sort, filter, groupby, etc. maybe use flow(sort,filter,max... very confused how to get this going

Comment: got lodash working when starting with an array. never got custom iterables working. es6 vs. 5 issue? typescript? don't know. looked through code on lodash and it doesn't seem lazy at all. `map` seems to create entirely new array each time; ugly. i just don't get it. will look at `linq` library, `immutable.js`, etc.